# Magento - Tag wishlist products in admin -> order

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

if i add a product to my wishlist then i add to cart and buy, i'd like to have a tag (in the order admin page )  that say me : "hey this order come from a wishlist! "..
is it possible??
Thanks

Comment: How would the semantics work here? If the product is added from the wishlist interface, or just the catalog? What about different sizes or colors of the same thing?

Comment: Only from wishlist to cart. I need to know if product is from wishlist!